# Why my AWS S3 Bucket credentials not working in production?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular15

I have the code to connect to my AWS S3 Bucket and get all folders and files while in development. On the other hand, it is not working after deploying to render.com

I have used old credentials and it is not working but shows in AWS panel last time used (which means it is working). I created a new ones and used them but i see in AWS that it is never used (to me this means that there is something wrong with configuration).

environment:

```
export const environment = {
    aws: {
        accessKeyId: '???',
        secretAccessKey: '???',
        region: 'ap-south-1'
    }
}
```

in my service.ts:

```
const bucket = new S3(environment.aws);
```

this is working in localhost (development) and when deploy to render.com, I have defined the same variables and values on that site but when it is done deploying, I am not getting connection to my bucket (I can confirm this because in my AWS console I can see that the credentials are not used and if I press F12 I get error:

```
main.bced92b277708982.js:1 ERROR CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

so I am not sure what is wrong? is region misplaced or is it something else?